# PHP Mysql - Illegal mix of collations when using CONCAT

Tags: mysql, mysqli, php

Iv'e been trying to concat two columns from my table and perform a LIKE on them

Here is the mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM stops WHERE CONCAT_WS(name, ' ', desc) LIKE
'%This%' AND CONCAT_WS(name, ' ', desc) LIKE '%is%' AND 
CONCAT_WS(name, ' ', desc) LIKE '%a%' 
AND CONCAT_WS(name, ' ', desc) LIKE '%test%'
```

When I run it via my php code or phpmyadmin I get the following error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_bin,NONE) and 
(utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

Iv'e been checking similar questions about this topic and saw that a lot of 
the answers told to change the collation of the database.

I already changed all database, tables and fields collcation to utf8_general_ci

When I run the same query exactly in Navicat it works just fine.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: does it matter that the `CONCAT_WS` doesn't have the separator first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the database and tables -> `character` to `utf8`

```
   ALTER DATABASE db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: That was the problem. But I was sure the collation was already utf8_general_ci. Nevermind now, thanks!